# Open riser stairs with squeaky treads

Tags: stairs

How do you make stair treads with an open riser stop squeaking?  The treads are connected to the stringer with brackets.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://www.familyhandyman.com/floor/repair/how-to-repair-squeaky-stairs/view-all

Answer (score 1):

You could try tighting the brackets. If the brackets are screwed on unscrew remove thread and apply some adhesive like F-26 or Liquid Nail then reinstall. If that's not possible you could screw or nail thru top of thread directly to the riser.  This old school trick might be an option, squirting a small amount of either baby powder or graphite between the tread and riser. I'm guessing the stairs are made of wood.